# Binding not work for property "class"

Tags: css, sapui5

In my `state` model I have:

```
...
"elementX": {valueState:"Success", valueStateText:"Great!" },
...
```

and in the XLMView I use a `Text` element:

```
<Text  text="{state>/elementX/valueStateText}" class="Success"/>
```

In my style.css file I have:

```
.Success{
    color: #008000;
}
```

All work fine and I see the green text!

**But** if bind `class` to `valueState` propery

```
<Text  text="{state>/elementX/valueStateText}" class="{state>/elementX/valueState}"/>
```

I see the text in black (not in green)... Why?

Using another component as Object Satus not have a good style in my form:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the class property is not bindable - it is not even a real property.

Anyhow the workaround to achieve what your are planning is easy: You have to use a formatter on any property and in that formatter you add/remove the class with the `addStyleClass`/`removeStyleClass` method.

```
<Text text="{ parts: [ 'state>/elementX/valueStateText', 'state>/elementX/valueState' ], formatter: 'my.static.Formatter.format' }" />

my.static.Formatter.format = function(sValueStateText, sValueStateClass) {
  // this refers to the control in a static formatter
  // set the class on the control via code
  if (sValueStateClass) {
    this.addStyleClass(sValueStateClass);
  }

  // statically return the desired text to make it appear in the text property
  return sValueStateText;
};
```

BR
Chris